# Filebeat add tags per file directory

Tags: tags, filebeat

I have the same kind of log file that uses the same grok patterns to match, however they are in different folders and I want to tag them accordingly. How would I go about it?

Would something like this work:

```
    filebeat.inputs:
    - type: log
      enabled: true

      paths:
        - /opt/IBM/WebSphere/server_one/SystemOut.log
      tags: ["server_one"]
        
      paths:
        - /opt/IBM/WebSphere/server_two/SystemOut.log
      tags: ["server_two"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Having multiple log entries with different tags worked.

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /opt/IBM/WebSphere/server_one/SystemOut.log
  tags: ["server_one"]

- type: log
  enabled: true        
  paths:
    - /opt/IBM/WebSphere/server_two/SystemOut.log
  tags: ["server_two"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom fields to the events and then use conditional filtering in Logstash.

In order to do this, you need to define multiple prospectors in the Filebeat configuration. Now, group the files that need the same processing under the same prospector so that the same custom fields can be added.

More reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/1.1/multiple-prospectors.html

Comment: Should I then use: filebeat.prospectors: ?

Comment: Yes. Check the example in the link I have provided